# vuerouter editing link and do I store the state?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using vuerouter really for the first time and I am trying to dynamically add a url name to the hyperlink of the route. Not sure what I am doing here, {{message}} would show the name and I am trying to concatenate that to the existing url--what am I doing wrong?

secondly, because these pages are dynamically generated, would I use vuex to store the state--? so that others could see the pages--?

```js
const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }
const Foo = {
template: '<div>Foo {{n }}, {{b}}</div>',
props: ['n', 'b']
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/', component: Foo, props: route => ({

    })}
  ]
})
        new Vue({
            router,
          el: '#app',
          data: {

              message:''
            }        
          })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>

            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>

<body class="container">
        <div id="app">

            <h2>Generator</h2>

            <input v-model="message" placeholder="Enter Plan Year"> {{message}} Year<br><br>
            These pages are automatically generated:<br>
            <strong> CardMain_{{message}}.html</strong><br>
           <strong> Card_{{message}}.html</strong><br>
           <strong> state_{{message}}.html</strong><br>
           <strong> Log_{{message}}.html</strong><br>
           <strong> Log2_{{message}}.html</strong><br><br>
           <router-link to="/">/home</router-link>
           <router-link to="url/+'{{message}}+'">eCard</router-link>
           <router-link to="/foo/5/5">Directory</router-link>
           <router-view></router-view>
      
             <p><button class="btn btn-primary">Generate</button></p>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate the url, what you want is to use a v-bind on the route, you can do this by replacing the "to" with ":to"
Once you have that, the content of the attribute ":to" behaves as if it was javascript and you have access to all the properties of the vue component so you can just do:

`<router-link to="'url/' + message">eCard</router-link>`

However this route hasnt actually been registerd so it will not load anything.
Instead you may want to register a route that accepts a parameter

```
{ path: '/url/:id', name: 'ecard', component: eCardComponent , props: true }
```

In this way you can call your route as

`<router-link :to="{ name: 'ecard', params:{ id: message } }">eCard</router-link>`

Then you can do whatever you need in that component, like loading info from a database for that particular id.

Additionally, Vuex only works on the current tab (unless you use some code to syncronize it with the localstorage, [like this example](https://benjaminlistwon.com/blog/vuex-chat-part-2/)) and even then it would not persit it across machines.

```js
const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }
const eCardComponent = { template: '<div>Ecard :{{id}}</div>', props:['id'] }
const Foo = {
template: '<div>Foo {{n }}, {{b}}</div>',
props: ['n', 'b']
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/', component: Foo, props: route => ({

    })},
    { path: '/url/:id', name:'ecard', component: eCardComponent, props: true },
  ]
})
        new Vue({
            router,
          el: '#app',
          data: {

              message:''
            }        
          })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>

            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>

<body class="container">
        <div id="app">

            <h2>Generator</h2>

            <input v-model="message" placeholder="Enter Plan Year"> {{message}} Year<br><br>
            These pages are automatically generated:<br>
            <strong> CardMain_{{message}}.html</strong><br>
           <strong> Card_{{message}}.html</strong><br>
           <strong> state_{{message}}.html</strong><br>
           <strong> Log_{{message}}.html</strong><br>
           <strong> Log2_{{message}}.html</strong><br><br>
           <router-link to="/">/home</router-link>
           <router-link :to="{ name: 'ecard', params:{ id: message } }">eCard</router-link>
           <router-link to="/foo/5/5">Directory</router-link>
           <router-view></router-view>
      
             <p><button class="btn btn-primary">Generate</button></p>
              </div>
```

Comment: So you recommend storing these dynamically generated pages to a database?

Comment: I would store the identifier/id of the page and whatever info you need to generate it. That way you can retrieve that list and print the router links on the page using a v-for/iteration